# AndroidStudio dando erro inusitado ao abrir arquivos fontes do projeto

Tags: android, android-studio

o AndroidStudio está abrindo errado os arquivos do projeto,
veja um dos casos o fonte CMapBuffer.java. Só para reforçar, é o mesmo arquivo sendo aberto pelo editor de texto do SO e pela IDE, no primeiro abre o arquivo .java corretamente e no segundo abre um XML que não corresponde ao arquivo CMapBuffer.java.

quando abro CMapBuffer.java no editor de texto do SO:

```
    package lib.map.buffer;

    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

    import lib.map.CMapListenerList;
    import lib.map.def.MAP;

    //-------------------------------------

    public class CMapBuffer
    {
      private static final CMapData m_mbu[] = new CMapData[MAP.count];

      //-----------------------------------

      public static void put(int key, FrameLayout root, MapView view)
      {
        m_mbu[key] = new CMapData(root,view);
      }

      //-----------------------------------

      public static void put(int key, GoogleMap map)
      {
        m_mbu[key].m_map = map;
        m_mbu[key].m_mli = new CMapListenerList(map);
        m_mbu[key].m_view.onResume();
      }

*** E assim vai, corretamente.
```

Quando abro CMapBuffer.java no AndroidStudio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2017 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/topPanel"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:gravity="top|center_horizontal">

    <!-- If the client uses a customTitle, it will be added here. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_template"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@android:id/icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="24dp"
            android:maxWidth="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Demorei para descobrir que o arquivo fonte estava certo no HD. Tenho um backup recente do projeto, mas copiar o arquivo não resolve. Tentativas que sem sucesso:

- Exclusão do .gradle
- Exclusão do .idea
- Exclusão dos arquivos IML
- Copiar o arquivo fonte pelo SO
- Copiar o arquivo fonte do SO para o AndroidStudio
- Clear cache restart

Segue uma imagem da tela do AndroidStudio para reforçar a estranheza.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Conteúdo do proguard-rules.pro exibido no AndroidStudio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string msgid="4600421777120114993" name="abc_action_bar_home_description">"Krmarjenje domov"</string>
    <string msgid="1594238315039666878" name="abc_action_bar_up_description">"Krmarjenje navzgor"</string>
    <string msgid="3588849162933574182" name="abc_action_menu_overflow_description">"Več možnosti"</string>
    <string msgid="4076576682505996667" name="abc_action_mode_done">"Končano"</string>
    <string msgid="7468859129482906941" name="abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all">"Pokaži vse"</string>
    <string msgid="2031811694353399454" name=
```

Conteúdo do proguard-rules.pro - correto - exibido no bloco de notas

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\Android\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Comment: O erro esta acontecendo porque um arquivo que deveria ter a extensão xml está salvo como java.
Verifica se esta mesmo no caminho que o androidStudio está procurando

Comment: É o mesmo arquivo fonte - CMapBuffer.java - o primeiro aberto pelo editor de texto do SO e o segundo aberto pela IDE

Answer (score 0):

Ao que me parece, isso é um arquivo de layout. Você precisa trocar a extensão dele de `.java` pra `.xml` e trocar o local do arquivo. Tem que tirar ele do pacote que está, e colocar na pasta `res/layout`.

Comment: É o mesmo fonte - CMapBuffer.java - o primeiro aberto pelo editor de texto do SO e o segundo aberto pela IDE

Comment: Não tem como ser o mesmo. Clica com o botão direito em cima do arquivo que está com erro no Android Studio e vai em "Show in Explorer". Você vai ver que são arquivos diferentes.

Comment: Fiz isso: "Show in Explorer", abriu o local do arquivo, abri com o bloco de notas exibe o arquivo CMapBuffer.java corretamente. Duplo clique sobre o arquivo no AndroidStudio exibe o XML. Por isso disse "inusitado", não dá pra enterder :(

Comment: parece que vou conseguir resolver - mais de um dia tentando - copiei os arquivos do projeto para uma pasta auxiliar e desta pasta copiei novamente para o AndroidStudio. Problema estranho, solução estranha.

Comment: Mas funcionou??

Comment: Estou fazendo e está resolvendo. É como se o AndroidStudio tivesse uma FAT e ao "recopiar" o arquivo ele se ajeita.